# 'Value' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, django, advanced-search

This is some code I wrote to give the result of advanced search for some subchannels that have there attributes and the values of the attributes each in a different table. It gives me this error: `'Value' object does not support indexing at line 35`

```
sub_id = request.GET['sub_ch_id']
attributes = Attribute.objects.filter(subchannel_id = sub_id)
values =[]
print "attributes"
# print request
post = []
value_obj =[]
for w in attributes:
    name = w.name
    print request.GET[name]
    values.append(request.GET[name])



result_search_obj = []
flag = False
result_search = []
result = []
post = []
i = 0
f = i+1
# post_temp = ""

# print "HIIIIII", len(result_search_obj)
for j in range(0,len(attributes)):
    # print 'EREEEEEEE'
    result_search_obj+=(Value.objects.filter(attribute_id = attributes[j].id 
        , value = values[j]))
    # print '1st loop'
result_search = [[] for o in result_search_obj]    
for k in range(0,len(result_search_obj)):
    # print '2 loop'
    for l in range(0,len(result_search_obj)):
        print 'why u dnt go here'

        result_search[k].append(result_search_obj[k][l].Post_id)
        # print '4 loop'
for a in range(0,len(result_search)):

    result_search.sort(len(result_search[k]))
    # print '6 loop'
for h in range(0,len(result_search)):

    post_temp = ""
    # print '3 loop'
    for g in result_search[h]:
        tmp=result_search[h]
        loc = temp[g]
        if loc == result_search[h+1][g]:
            flag = True
            post_temp = tmp[g]
            break
    post = post_temp
print post

return HttpResponse('filter_post_channel.html', {'posts' : post})
```

Comment: Dear Mohamed, line 35 is empty in your code, is this your full file? Or could you point which line is raising the error?

Comment: Show us output for `print result_search_obj` after first loop, please

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this line:

```
result_search_obj+=(Value.objects.filter(attribute_id = attributes[j].id 
    , value = values[j]))
```

You are creating a tuple and appending it to a list. You are expecting to add the tuple as a tuple, but Python flattens the tuple and adds its elements instead.

So you need to change your line as to create a list and to append it to `result_search_obj`

```
result_search_obj+= [ (Value.objects.filter(attribute_id = attributes[j].id 
    , value = values[j])) ]
```

Sample test

```
>>> x=[]
>>> x += (1, 2)
>>> x
[1, 2]
>>> x += [(1, 2)]
>>> x
[1, 2, (1, 2)]
>>> x += (1, 2)
>>> x
[1, 2, (1, 2), 1, 2]
>>>
```